# API Rate Limit responding invalid headers

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

Using Laravel7. The global api rate limit setting in kernel.php is overriding the api header response.   For example in api.php

```
 api.php 
    Route::get('/test1', function () {
    return 'test777';
})->middleware("throttle:5,1");;

   kernel.php
            'api' => [
                'throttle:60,1',
                \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            ],
```

When the max limit of 5 attempts is reached receiving 429 with invalid headers. It should be 5 attempts.
X-RateLimit-Limit       60
X-RateLimit-Remaining   56

Need to commment the  'throttle:60,1', in kernel.php to respond with proper x-rate headers.   Don't want to comment it as all other api have rate limit 60 requests per minute.  Is there any alternative to do it?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent conflicts in the cache key that handles the rate limiting you should give a name to your rate limit if it's different than the default:

```
Route::get('/test1', function () {
    return 'test777';
})->middleware("throttle:5,1,test1");
```

This way there would not be conflicts between the cache keys used to set the rate limit.

This is described in [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#rate-limiting) under "Rate limit segments"

Note that in Laravel 8 this has changed and now you can also use the `configureRateLimiting` function in your `RouteServiceProvider`:

```
protected function configureRateLimiting()
{
    RateLimiter::for('test1', function (Request $request) {
        return Limit::perMinute(5);
    });
}
```

Then you can use:

```
Route::get('/test1', function () {
    return 'test777';
})->middleware("throttle:test1");
```

The L8 approach allows much more control over rate limiting as well so it's worth considering an upgrade if you need good rate limiting functionality

Comment: Thanks for the info .  In Laravel 7 need to comment the api throttle in kernel.php to make it work even if I apply  the segments   ' })->middleware("throttle:5,1,test1");' . If I dont comment in kernel.php its still not working giving the incorrect x-limit headers set to 60

Comment: Is there any alternative in Laravel 7?